# C++ not reading anything from files

Tags: c++, io

I seem to be having a problem reading files. I am using Visual Studio Community 2013 and it will do everything but reading of files. I have checked to make sure the file being read and written is in the same directory. The following code is where I believe the problem to be:

```
if (inStream.bad())
{
    inStream.close();

    outStream.open(filename);
    outStream << "This is a test file: \nWelcome to the Dark Side!";
    outStream.close();
}

inStream.open(filename, ios::in);
if (inStream.good())
{
    while (getline(inStream, stream[1]))
    {
        stream[0] += stream[1] + '\n';
    }

    inStream.close();

}
else
{
    cout << "THIS FILE IS ROYALLY *jacked* UP!!!!" << endl;
}
```

and I get the "This file is royally jacked up" result. I don't understand why it's not reading. Please help.

Comment: The problem occurs probably because you are using `inStream.open(...)` regardless of whether `inStream` is in a good state or bad state.

Comment: Why would it matter? I thought the .good() was to make sure it opened correctly?

Comment: Nope, good is a default state, when no errors happened. When a file is opened, `stream` isn't automatically cleared to `good`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the lines:

```
if (inStream.bad())
{
    inStream.close();

    outStream.open(filename);
    outStream << "This is a test file: \nWelcome to the Dark Side!";
    outStream.close();
}

inStream.open(filename, ios::in);
if (inStream.good())
```

to

```
if (inStream.bad())
{
    inStream.close();

    outStream.open(filename);
    outStream << "This is a test file: \nWelcome to the Dark Side!";
    outStream.close();

    // Clear the state of the stream.
    inStream.clear();

    // Move this line inside the block.
    inStream.open(filename, ios::in);
}

if (inStream.good())
```

You don't want to call `open` on a valid `ifstream`.

Here's a sample program that demonstrates that calling `open` on a valid `ifstream` can make it invalid.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
   std::ifstream inFile("socc.in");
   if ( inFile.good() )
   {
      std::cout << "ifstream is good.\n";
   }

   inFile.open("socc.in");
   if ( inFile.good() )
   {
      std::cout << "ifstream is still good.\n";
   }
   else
   {
      std::cout << "ifstream is not good any more.\n";
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
ifstream is good.
ifstream is not good any more.
```

Comment: It worked, thank you so much, I'm slightly confused why closing it and reopening it outside the if doesn't work but somehow this made it work.

Comment: @DavidGreen, if `inStream` is good, there is nothing in your code to close it before opening it again.

Answer (score 0):

It might help to use `clear` before opening a new file, as `open` may not clear the flags on its own.

```
inStream.clear();
inStream.open(filename, ios::in);
```

You could also use `is_open` instead of `good`.

```
if(inStream.is_open()) {
    ...
```

Comment: I've tried that, now it is running the code in is_open however it still is not reading the input.

Comment: If you don't get your error and you'e not reading any input, it means that the file was opened successfully, but the reading has failed. Otherwise, your fiole could not be opened.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling inStream.clear() before doing anything with it. clear() clears the old flags like bad being true.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification as to what .clear() does, I was slightly confused on that until now.